# missing DLL - freetype262d.dll

Tags: c++, sdl, game-engine, sdl-ttf

I'm making a simple 2D game engine in C++ and to write text on the screen I want to use `SDL_ttf`.
The problem is that after I installed `SDL_ttf` an error message pops up saying that `freetype262d.dll` is missing. To fix this error I tried reinstalling `SDL_ttf` manually and via NuGet and searching for the dll file online to download it but it's to no avail.

[image: that's the error message]

Comment: Your needed step is to track down this file `freetype262d.dll`. Does it exist in your binaries? The `d` at the end typically means Debug.

Comment: Have you : _"Requires:  The latest stable release of SDL 2.0`"_ ?  https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/

Comment: Looks like you need to install the FreeType library as well. Apparently SDL_ttf itself does not include it itself.

Comment: @RichardCritten I do have tha lates version of SDL 2.0 installed.

Comment: BTW, you can build both of these pretty easy yourself with `vcpkg`. [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)

Comment: @JesperJuhl I installed the freetype library via NuGet but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @drescherjm can you elaborate on what you mean by asking if it exists in my binaries.

Comment: I meant is this file in the folder that contains the SDL dlls installed on your hard drive. I wanted you to use the search feature of windows to see if it was in a different path or something.

Comment: @JesperJuhl please comment your answer about mission the freetype library so I can up-vote it and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to install the FreeType library as well. Apparently SDL_ttf itself does not include it itself.